# Front End Versioning the ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, versioning

We've got an enterprise application running on ASP.NET MVC. We've recently started revamping the complete UI of the application. Now, when I say UI, its not simple CSS that I could put in a separate folder and load dynamically. Basically, the complete navigation structure, layout elements, everything is now being revamped. However, the overall code (controllers, models) remains pretty much same with some minor enhancements here and there. Now, we are supposed to roll out the revamped UI but at the same time also support the Old UI in parallel.

The objective is to run the new UI like `appURL/v2/` rest of the view urls remain the same.

Now, our objective is that we should not have to duplicating the controllers, models into another project.

So, what would be the best approach to serve different views globally across the application based on `/v2/` identifier for version in the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using areas you can serve different views using the same controllers. So you create a "v2" area with its own views, and route requests to "v2" accordingly:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "v2_default",
    "v2/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { area = "v2", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new string[] { "YourNamespace.Controllers" }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { area = "", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new string[] { "YourNamespace.Controllers" }
    );
```

Using this construct, both routes will look for the controllers in the same namespace.

Comment: The controller & action are same, but how do I define that it needs to pick up the View from v2 area without changing the code inside every action and putting an if/else for view.

Comment: @Vikram views should be resolved according to the area from the route values. So if you request an action through `/v2`, then the `Areas/v2/Views` directory should be accessed for that action.

Comment: tried it, the problem is that it expects the controller & action also to be defined in the area "/v2". if there is no controller in v2, it throws a 404 error. Any ideas, how I can mix the generic controller with v2 area views ?

Comment: @Vikram then perhaps you need to add `namespaces: new string[] { "YourNamespace.Controllers" }` to both routes. This principle should work, but I can't test the details at the moment.